# php random element from array no siblings

Tags: php, arrays, random, siblings

Trying to get an item randomly from array(`$colors`) without having two same colors next to each other.

```
<div class="list">
  <?php
  foreach ($team as $member):
    $index++;
  ?>
  <div class="member location-<?php echo strtolower($member->location); ?>">
    <a style="background: #FFF url('<?php echo $member->profileImage; ?>') no-repeat;" data-start-date="<?php echo $member->startDate; ?>">
      <?php shuffle($colors); // Shuffle the array ?>
      <span class="name" style="background-color: #<?php echo array_pop($colors)->color; ?>"><?php echo $member->name; ?></span>
      <span class="job-title"><span class="text"><?php echo $member->jobTitle; ?></span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Right now I have some cases when I'm getting a color next to each other.

How do I get each time a different color? I'd like to mention that `count($team) > count($colors)` (is greater).

**UPDATE:**

$colors looks like (I've just printed 3 items, the count is higher)

```
    array(18) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#112 (1) {
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "5ebedb"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#111 (1) {
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "c75d40"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#110 (1) {
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "faaf37"
    }
  }
```

Comment: So it's not really something random ;)

Comment: you could shuffle just once the array of collors before the foreach , also a question your array $colors has distinct colors or there are some of them more than once?

Comment: There will always be cases where you have colors next to each other, the way you're doing things now. This is an interesting question none the less. What should we understand from "same color"(we talking in the same hue range?)? You need some sort of way to tell when 2 colors are "not the same" anymore.

Comment: @Andrew: I only want to not have two colors that are next to each other. (for example blue to be next to blue; I don't care if I'll have another item that has the blue, which is 3 items after that or before)

Comment: @knets: $colors is a list of colors with not dupilicates. The only thing is that the count is lower that the loop itself

Comment: What does your color array look like?

Comment: @Andrew: updated my question, you may look at the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. I striped the html tags to make my solution more understandable.

```
$colors = [...]; // see your definition of the $color array
$colorCount = count($colors);
$lastColorId = null;
foreach ($team as $member)
{
    // choose a random color
    $colorId = rand(0,$colorCount-1);
    if ($lastColorId == $colorId) 
    {
        // take the next color if it's the same as the previous one
        $colorId = ($colorId + 1) % $colorCount;
    }
    $lastColorId = $colorId;
    // Get the color
    $color = $colors[$colorId]->color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really random since in case you do have the same color again
we'll have to do a math calculation to get another color.
We can use a `while` loop that runs a `rand` function but I believe it's not efficient, especially when we're talking about getting random colors for visual purpose.

Not the brightest solution but I believe it can do the job.

```
$colors = array('blue','red','green');

function getRandomColor($colors, $lastIndex = null){
  $rand = floor(rand(0, count($colors)));
  if(isset($lastIndex) && $rand == $lastIndex){
    if($rand == 0)
      $rand++;
    else //prevent offset: ($rand == count($colors))
      $rand--;
  }
    return array('color' => $colors[$rand], 'lastIndex' => $rand);
}
```

Usage, for the first time use:

```
$rand_color = getRandomColor($colors);
```

And after the first loop use:

```
$rand_color = getRandomColor($colors, $rand_color['lastIndex']);
```

You can simply use a simple condition for that matters to check if `$rand_color` is already been set or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$color1 = array(); 

  foreach ($team as $member) {
    // make copy of array everytime it beome empty. And work with the copy
    if (! $color1)  { $color1 = $colors; shuffle($colors); }
    ....
    echo array_pop($color1)->color;
    ...
  }
```